# Converting pdo object to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert a PDO object to a javascript array and having issues accessing the keys from the array.

```
<script> var groups = new Array(); </script>
<?php $groups = getGroups($_SESSION['userId']);             //turn group o
while ($row = $groups->fetch()){
echo "<script> groups.push('" . json_encode($row) . "'); </script>";
}
?>
```

If I console the array like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++){
    console.log(groups[i]);
    }
```

My console prints out this:

```
{"id":"5","teacherid":"1","name":"Honors","subject":"0","type":"custom","sid":"0","skillid":"0","grade":"8"}
```

However when I try to access one of the keys like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++){
    console.log(groups[i].name);
    }
```

I get undefined in the console.

I have found several posts that seem to indicate the syntax above should work, any thoughts?

Comment: you are encoding them as string. you need to parse them again. whats `console.log(typeof groups[i]);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure that the elements in the groups array are not strings (unparsed json) ? If this is the case, you can use JSON.parse on the string, and the try to access the name. Or you could drop the quotes around the object when generating on the server.

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting my head around JSON, that did the trick. I added var parsedGroup = JSON.parse(groups[i]); and then called the key by console.log(parsedGroup.name);

Comment: What you're suggesting __may__ work, but should there be a "'" in the string I think it'll break again. json_encode() returns a string which __is__ the Javascript code for a Javascript object. To use it you do not need to encase it with quotes as RyanY did, but just use it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
echo "<script> groups.push('" . json_encode($row) . "'); </script>";
```

Should be changed to

```
echo "<script> groups.push(" . json_encode($row) . "); </script>";
```

as json_encode makes sure they are already a Javascript object.